# TypeError: Amplify.configure is not a function with SvelteKit + Amplify AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, vite, sveltekit

I was doing some hands on with the new SvelteKit FE using AWS Amplify to use Cognito service to authenticated my app and everything run fine in dev mode. But then, I tried to build it for deployment and this is where the fun begin...

First, I was not able to simply build the app. There was an error with Vite not able to correctly "interpret" the "browser" field!? :

```
'request' is not exported by __vite-browser-external, imported by node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-provider-imds/dist/es/remoteProvider/httpRequest.js
```

The issue is documented here (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/3673) and here (https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ui/issues/268).

I apply the solution suggested but ErikCH to add an alias in the svelte.config.cjs file:

```
resolve: {
        alias: {
          "./runtimeConfig": "./runtimeConfig.browser"
        }
      }
```

So now, I was back on track since the app build without an hitch. But then, I tried to run the app with an "npm run preview" but it stop dead on this message:

```
TypeError: Amplify.configure is not a function
```

I double check my code and I don't see anything missing or out of place. Here's the imports and call of that function :

```
...
import Amplify from '@aws-amplify/core';
import Auth from "@aws-amplify/auth";
import awsconfig from "../aws-exports";

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);
...
```

As mention before, the project run in dev mode, it all in pure Javascript, nothing really fancy. I updated to the latest package of everythings... here my actual version:

```
@sveltejs/kit": "^1.0.0-next.159
vite v2.5.1
"aws-amplify": "^4.2.5"
node v14.17.5
npm v7.21.1
```

I saw comments about removing completely Amplify libs and write wrappers to call Cognito directly but I found this not very productive and cumbersome. So, my last resort is the call Stackoverflow to the rescue! ;-)

Edit #1 I realize that this error occur in the app.js, that is the server side of the FE app. This is not right. This MUST run in the browser. How come it end up in the server side ???

Comment: what is this `runtimeConfig.js` file? I don't have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure this gets you on the right track, but one thing that has helped me out with package import weirdness, especially when it's between dev and build, is [vite's `optimizedDeps` config directive](https://vitejs.dev/config/#dep-optimization-options). Perhaps something within the AWS package(s) is not liking the pre-bundling that vite is doing  and you need to exclude it? This might help explain why things run fine while in dev.

Comment: Well, I saw this directive in some issues that was open on the sveltekit github but I was not able to find the proper values for the Amplify libs. I finally give up on Amplify and decided to use the only lib I really needed (cognito). (ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66701358/how-to-use-amazon-cognito-without-amplify). And now it compile no problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had to change `Amplify` to a named import for preview to work for me after build.

```
import { Amplify } from '@aws-amplify/core'
```

---

And in case anyone faced 'dev' issues with Amplify + SvelteKit, adding the following to the top of the `<head>` tag in `app.html` may help.

```html
    <script>
      var global = global || window
      var Buffer = Buffer || []
      var process = process || { env: { DEBUG: undefined }, version: [] }
    </script>
```

---

My versions:

- Node.js: 14.18.0
- @aws-amplify/auth: 4.3.11
- @aws-amplify/core: 4.3.3
- @sveltejs/kit: 1.0.0-next.190
- typescript: 4.4.4